# c# subquery not working

Tags: c#, mysql

I like to add subquery to mysql database, but it gives me error.

```
string q = "INSERT INTO table1(isbn,date,ID,title) 
values('" + this.textBoxisbn.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','" + this.textBoxk.Text + "'(select title from books where isbn=" + textBox1.Text + "')'" + "');";
```

Comment: Can you post the error also?

Comment: comma missing before sub-query

Comment: You're missing a comma, possibly quotes as well, but that aside you should be using prepared statements which would automatically handle a lot of these things for you.

Comment: SQL injection, look it up and parameterize your commands or use a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Make the query *readable* with a help of *verbatim strings* and *string interpolation*:

```
   string q = 
     $@"INSERT INTO table1(
          Isbn,
          Date,
          ID,
          Title) 
        VALUES(
          '{textBoxisbn.Text}',
          '{dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}',
          '{textBoxk.Text}',
          (SELECT Title
             FROM Books
            WHERE Isbn = '{textBox1.Text}'))";
```

and you'll easily find out all syntax errors in the query. Further improvement is changing the query into *parametrized* one:

```
   string q = 
     $@"INSERT INTO table1(
          Isbn,
          Date,
          ID,
          Title) 
        VALUES(
          @prm_Isbn,
          @prm_Date,
          @prm_Id,
          (SELECT Title
             FROM Books
            WHERE Isbn = @prm_IsbnForTitle))";
```